# Publish Branch to Master without another branch changes - Github

Tags: php, laravel, git, github

I have one issue regarding git. I hope you can understand.

There is two branches from develop.

1. feature-login
2. roles-permission
   [image]
   Now roles-permission branch is developed perfectly with database changes and all the things. But we don't want to deploy it on develop.

Now we are working on feature-login branch and we want to pull roles-permission branch. So I can pull this branch. But if we are going to deploy only feature-login branch than the changes of roles-permission branch is also deploy. So we don't require this thing. I want only feature-login changes.

So Can anyone help me with this. I hope you all understand this question.

Comment: So you don't want to directly merge `roles-permissions` into `develop` but you do want that branch in your `feature-login` branch? Then you want to merge `feature-login` with `develop`?

Comment: Thanks @Peppermintology, Yes. I want roles-permission branch into feature-login branch and don't want to deploy roles-permission branch. Is there any other method or branch flow that I want to follow without merge.

Comment: So merge `roles-permissions` into `feature-login`, rebase `feature-login` and do a `pull request` into `develop`?

Comment: Git itself has essentially no access / permission controls (there's some very limited "shared for group access" for Unix/Linux style group IDs, but that does not cover this case). So *Git* is no help at all here. However, many hosting sites, including Git*Hub*, *add on* access control. You'll be looking at the hosting site's offerings.